# Show an element only if the data given by the Api exists

Tags: javascript, html, pokeapi

I'm using Pokeapi and want to display the types of the pokemon in 2 different element bc I'm applying a style (the background color) according to the type of the pokemon. The problem is that it shows the first 3 pokemon but not the fouth bc it has only one type and it can't find the second type (which doesn't exist) in the data given by the api.

Here's my JS :

```
function displayPokemon (pokemon) {
    const pokemonEl = document.createElement('li');
    const name = pokemon.name;
    const type1 = pokemon.types[0].type.name;
    const type2 = pokemon.types[1].type.name;
    const pokemonHTMLString =
        `
        <div class="pokemon_container ${type1} ${type2}">
            <div class="pokemon_container_image">
                <img class="pokemon_container_image_sprite" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png" loading="lazy" alt="${name}"/>
                <img class="pokemon_container_image_shiny" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/${pokemon.id}.png" loading="lazy" alt="${name}"/>
            </div>
            <h3 class="pokemon_number">#${pokemon.id.toString().padStart(3, '0')}</h3>
            <h2 class="pokemon_name" onClick = "selectPokemon(${pokemon.id})">${name}</h2>
            <a class="pokemon_type" id="${type1}">
                <img id="${type1}" alt="${type1}"></img>
                <span>${type1}</span>
            </a>
            <a class="pokemon_type" id="${type2}">
                <img id="${type2}" alt="${type2}"></img>
                <span>${type2}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    `
    pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
    pokedex.appendChild(pokemonEl);
};
```

Here's the error : "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: pokemon.types[1] is undefined"

Before that I was mapping the types and showing them in one element but I want to do 2 separate elements and I don't know if my code is wrong and I have to modify something or if I have to create a function or an if else statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for "nullability" of the second optional type (variable) and react to that scenario (no second type) to avoid this kind of errors where you depend on something which does not exist. The simplest way, in this case, would be to use if-else statements to change the displayed HTML.

Comment: As an alternate solution you could eliminate type1 and type2 variables and use foreach over types array. It would remove the duplication of code for the anchors in the end of your div, and also prepare your function to handle even more types in future.

Comment: I tried to do an if else statement to check make the anchor tag disappear if it's null but the problem is that the second type is not null but it doesn't exist

Comment: @ÁdámRévész Can i separate the elements into multiple anchor tags ?